# Order of domain interval plots differently on Contour

Tags: plotting

```
h = 2; k = 8; p = 10;
g1 = ContourPlot[{(x - h)^1.27 + (y - k)^3.75 == 1}, {x, 0, p}, {y, 0,
     p}, ContourStyle -> Red];
g2 = ContourPlot[{(x - h)^1.27 + (y - k)^3.75 == 1}, {y, 0, p}, {x, 0,
     p}, ContourStyle -> Blue] ;
g3 = Plot3D[{(x - h)^1.27 + (y - k)^3.75}, {x, 0, p}, {y, 0, p}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red];
g4 = Plot3D[{(x - h)^1.27 + (y - k)^3.75}, {y, 0, p}, {x, 0, p}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue] ;
Show[{g1, g2}]
Show[{g3, g4}]
```

Same function but order of domain interval interchangeably  mentioning seems to result in a different (inverse) function..

EDIT1:

Actually the import of my question is for generalization:    *$(x-y) $ domain interval plot order reversal  supplies a means to visualize 2D/3D Contour and Monge inverse function plots ..* Is it correct?

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. You've switched the x and y axes, so the blue line should be a reflection of the red line about the line y = x. Whatever variable comes first is plotted along the x-axis in the contour plot, and the second variable is plotted along the y-axis.

Comment: In Plot3D also it is expected to be same function but differently depicted?

Comment: Yes, Plot3D will also do the same. Try `Show[Plot3D[Exp[a] Sin[b], {a, 0, 5}, {b, 0, 5}], Plot3D[Exp[a] Sin[b], {b, 0, 5}, {a, 0, 5}]]` and you'll see that there is a seam where the two plots are reflected about the line `a = b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal for Mathematica to take the first variable as the "x" axis, and the second variable as they "y" axis for for `DensityPlot`, `ContourPlot`, `Plot3D`, and possibly others as well. We don't technically have to label the variables as "x" and "y", we could just as easily use "a" and "b", so MMA just takes them in the order we specify them.

Switching the order of the variables will result in the function being mirrored across the line y = x (or a = b or whatever variables we're using).

This is most easily seen with `Plot3D`:

```
Show[
  Plot3D[
     Exp[a] Sin[b], 
     {a, 0, 5}, 
     {b, 0, 5}
  ], 
  Plot3D[
     {None, Exp[a] Sin[b]}, 
     {b, 0, 5}, 
     {a, 0, 5}
  ]
]
```

[image: Mirroring Plot3D about the line y = x.]

Comment: Actually the import of my question is for generalization: domain interval plot order reversal supplies a means to visualize 2D/3D Contour and Monge inverse function plots .. Is it correct?

Comment: @Narasimham I'm not sure what a Monge inverse function is, but in general I would say you can plot the inverse with this method. Of course, you can also do something like `ContourPlot[Evaluate[y == x^2 /. {x -> y, y -> x}], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5} ]` and switch x and y directly. They amount to the same thing as switching the domains.

Comment: Monge form is z= f(x,y) now stands apart from z= f(y,x)  as you pictured above.